# How to check Collections.insert() is Successfully Inserted or not in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How to check Collections.insert() is Successfully Inserted or not with pymongo?. For example :

```
db.results.insert_one({'a':aaa})
```

How to know the above insert query is successfully inserted or not?

Comment: on which side? on yours or on `MongoDb`'s?

Comment: Documentation of [`insert_one()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) shows you it returns an [`InsertOneResult`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I catch an error of insertion?

Comment: >  insertStatus = self.db['Record'].insert_one({'name' : 'bar' })        
      >                       print(insertStatus.acknowledged)